# Flutter Dart App RangeError only on specific devices (not simulator)

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter

My Flutter app has a list that loads data from a Firebase Firestore database. It loads fine on all simulator devices (and some real iOS devices) but breaks on actual iPhone 7 devices only. The following error is what I'm getting on iPhone7 :

`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

I'm not really sure where to begin debugging this error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my list generator code:

```
return new ListView(
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return _buildActivityItem(context,
      new Activity(
        activity: document['activity'],
        dateCreated: document['dateCreated'],
        food: document['food'],
        id: document.documentID,
        sentiment: document['sentiment'],
        text: document['text'],
      )
    );
  }).toList(),
);

Widget _buildActivityItem(BuildContext context, Activity activity) {
  // Format Date
  var formatter = new DateFormat('E., MMMM d').add_j();
  var today = new DateFormat('E').format(new DateTime.now()) == new DateFormat('E').format(activity.dateCreated);
  String formattedDateCreated = today ? new DateFormat().add_j().format(activity.dateCreated) : formatter.format(activity.dateCreated);

  // Format Activity
  String emoji = activity.activity == 'Exercise' ? '‍' 
    : activity.food.length > 0 ? '' 
      : '';

  // List Foods
  String getFoodList = activity.food.join(', ');

  return Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      border: new Border(
        bottom: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor)
      )
    ),
    child: ListTile(
      leading: new Text(
        emoji,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 34.0
        )
      ),
      title: new Text(activity.text),
      subtitle: activity.activity.length > 0 ?  
        new Text(activity.activity )
        : activity.food.length > 0 ? new Text(getFoodList) 
          : null,
      trailing: new Text(formattedDateCreated),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Test with hard coded input once to verify whether the issue is in device or in input.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no difference with `flutter clean`, still works fine on simulators and breaks only on a real iPhone 7 device

Comment: @VinothKumar Data is not the issue, the erred list shows the correct amount of list items but each one renders an error message rather than the content. Keep in mind all data is showing correctly on all devices / simulators aside from iPhone 7 (actual device only, simulator works fine)

Comment: As of my knowledge Range errors in flutter will happen if you are accessing a value using a key from a Map where the key doesn't exists.

Comment: print each document and post the result here. This may give us some clue.

Comment: @VinothKumar how would you like me to print them out (what exactly do you want to see)?

Comment: Before returning _buildActivityItem try to print the document

Comment: Hey @AlecSibilia. If you're using Firebase, why not use StreamBuilder instead of ListView?